# 8-speed MICROSHIFT shifters and ultegra RD-R8000-SS derailleur

Tags: derailleur, gravel

I have Decathlon B'Twin Triban 500 with 8-speed MICROSHIFT shifters in the back. I am in the process of turning this commuting bike into my gravel bike. I already added new wheels and 35mm tires, Shimano chain and cassette.

Now, I have an extra Ultegra RD-R8000-SS 11 speed derailleur that I was thinking to use instead of the MICROSHIFT one. MICROSHIFT is ok but not that crisp. The question is, would it Ultegra derailleur work in this setting and what needs to be adjusted (e.g., limit screws)?

Comment: I doubt the derailleur will make much of a difference. Usually shifting performance is all about cables and shifters.

Comment: @Michael The Ultegra derailleur will have far less side-to-side play than the Microshift, which results in cleaner and more precise shifting.

Comment: @MaplePanda Indeed, the Microshift derailleur seems a sort of loose, I guess because the quality of spring and components is not the greatest, and as a result the chain is also bit too loose.

Answer (score 3):

No, Microshift is usually compatible with Shimano (As far as I know, all except Advent 9 speed), but Shimano 8 speed is not compatible with Shimano 11 speed as the derailleurs have different pull ratios.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to use an 8 speed microshift-brand shifter with an 11 speed rear derailleur? The cable pull ratio will not work for you, regardless if you have an 8 or 11 speed cassette.

Your best option (ie the safest) is to use all 8 speed or all 11 speed parts. That means rear derailleur, right-hand shifter, cassette, and chain, and it would be advisable to stay with shimano parts (while avoiding Tiagra 10 speed, which has an unusual pull ratio.)

So go for an 11 speed Ultegra or 105 rear mech/cassette and any 11 speed chain.